# How to get set of character of string in same order as in parent string in C++

Tags: c++, string, data-structures

I have a string and want to remove duplicates from it, but I want it in same order. `std::set or std::unordered_set` does not seem to help. I there any DS or have to tackle this manually? Example:-
"ddbbccaa" should be "dbca".

Comment: What should be returned when the input is `"ddbbddaab"` (non-continuous duplicate characters exist)?

Comment: according to first occurrence in this case "dba"

Comment: `std:: unique`?

Comment: What does`DS` mean?

Comment: @Alan Birtles I meant Data Structure (DS)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. iterate over the input string
2. add characters to result string when you haven't seen the character before

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>

std::string removeDuplicates(const std::string& str) {
    std::string result;
    std::unordered_set<char> seen;
    for (char c : str) {
        if (seen.find(c) == seen.end()) {
            result += c;
            seen.insert(c);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void) {
    std::cout << removeDuplicates("ddbbccaa") << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```